# Angular Ui-router scope sharing on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

> app.js

```
.state('stats',{
        url:'/stats/:id',
        //abstract : true,
        controller : 'statsController'
        //controllerAs: 'statsDetails',
        //templateUrl : 'app/templates/statsDetails.html'
    })
        .state('details',{
            url : '',
            controller : 'statsController'
            //name : 'stats'
            //templateUrl : 'app/templates/statsDetails.html'
        })
```

> statsController.js

```
app.controller('statsController',function($scope,$state,StatsFactory){

//FOR PARENT STATE CALL GET BASIC DETAILS
if($state.current.name == "stats"){
    $scope.id_campaign = $state.params.id;
    StatsFactory.getOptCampaign($scope.id_campaign).then(function(data) {
        $scope.OptCampaignDetail = data.data[0];

        StatsFactory.getRemList($scope.OptCampaignDetail.key_campaign)
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.remList = data.data;
            $state.go('details'); //cannot use getAll
            console.log($state);
        });

    });
}

//FOR AL  DETAILS WITH REMUNARETION LIST
if($state.current.name == 'details'){
    console.log($state.current.name);
    console.log($scope.remList);

}
```

});

> inside 'details' state i am not able to get parent scope variable .i tried with abstract state also but not able to access $scope.remList.Please give me some suggestion I m stacked here morning.By the way, I m new in angular

Comment: your states are not defined correctly.. you should specify that 'stats.details' has parent:'stats' .. then if you want the child state to inherit the parent state.. why don't you include it in a ui-view inside the parents template ?

Comment: app : .state('stats.detail',{ ..} || controller : $state.go('stats.details');console.log($state.curent.name); => 'stats' .so its not changing the state.Now response checking only in console later i ll add view.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the data you can pass it through $state.go:

```
$state.go('details', {remList: $scope.remList});
```

And in your app.js:

```
.state('stats',{
        url:'/stats/:id',
        //abstract : true,
        controller : 'statsController'
        //controllerAs: 'statsDetails',
        //templateUrl : 'app/templates/statsDetails.html'
    })
        .state('details',{
            url : '',
            controller : 'statsController',
            params: {remList: null} //default param
            //name : 'stats'
            //templateUrl : 'app/templates/statsDetails.html'
        })
```

You can access it later with $stateParams.remList.